# Jump Point Search result are not correct

Tags: c#, algorithm, path-finding

After I completed the how to make a A* pathfinding I wanted to learn more about Jump Point Search.
I did some reasearch how to make one by reading the
[orginal paper](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~dharabor/data/papers/harabor-grastien-aaai11.pdf) about it.

So after reading it a couple of times I try it for myself so I made one and it works short of.
so the problem is that he can find a path but not in the most best way see images what I mean.

[image: The result]

[image: Same result but worse]

So my first thought was that I did something wrong with the lowest Fcost so try to change that first but that was not answer. then I looked into the Sucessor function if I did something wrong try to change the order of the script but the result stay the same.
after that I looked into the jump code. But to be honest I don't see it what I did wrong either.

Then I try to find the answer here but, most of the answers resluted in the same result.

Maybe it can be that I have forgot something that this algoritme needs.

sucessor function.

```
    List<Node> IDSucessor(Node currentNode,Node start,Node goal)
{
    List<Node> sucessors = new List<Node>();
    List<Node> neighbors = new List<Node>();
    neighbors = Neigbors(currentNode);
    foreach (Node n in neighbors)
    {
        Node node = n;
        node = Jump(currentNode, n.x - currentNode.x, n.y - currentNode.y, start, goal);
        if (node != null)
        {
            if (!closedList.Contains(node))
            {
                int newMovementCost = (int)currentNode.GCost + GetDistance(currentNode, n);
                if (newMovementCost < node.GCost || !openList.Contains(node))
                {
                    node.GCost = newMovementCost;
                    node.HCost = GetDistance(n, goal);
                    node.FCost = n.GCost + n.HCost;
                    node.parent = currentNode;
                    if (!openList.Contains(node))
                    {
                        sucessors.Add(node);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return sucessors;
}
```

Jump Function

```
Node Jump(Node currentNode,int x,int y,Node start,Node goal)
{
    Node n = RetunNodeDir(currentNode, x, y);

    if (n==null)
    {
        //if n is null return null
        return null;
    }

    if (n.Col)
    {
        //if n collider return null.
        return null;
    }

    if (n.x == goal.x && n.y==goal.y)
    {
        //if it's a goal then the n will be a sucessor
        goalFounded = true;
        return n;
    }

    //if A neigbor is forced than return n as it's sucessor.
    if (IsForced(n, x, y, start, goal))
    {
        return n;
    }

    //if diangle
    if(x!=0 && y!=0)
    {
        if (IsForecedDiangle(n, x, y, start, goal))
        {

            return n;
        }

        if (Jump(n, x, 0, start, goal) != null || Jump(n, 0, y, start, goal) != null)
        {
            return n;
        }
    }

    //jump again
    return Jump(n, x, y, start, goal);
}
```

Force node horizontal. the vertical is the same code but has a diffrent coordination direction. the diangle use also the same code but it needed a extra agrument in the function.

```
 bool IsForcedHor(Node currentNode,int dirX)
{
    Node up = RetunNodeDir(currentNode, 0,  1);
    Node down = RetunNodeDir(currentNode, 0,  - 1);
    if(up!=null)
    {
        if(up.Col)
        {
            //check next to him.
            Node upNext = RetunNodeDir(currentNode, dirX,  1);
            if(upNext!=null)
            {
                if(!upNext.Col)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if(down!=null)
    {
        if(down.Col)
        {
            Node downNext = RetunNodeDir(currentNode, dirX, - 1);
            if (downNext != null)
            {
                if (!downNext.Col)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I hope I gave you enough information.

kind regards,
codinG